# How to write Spark SQL batch job results to the Apache Druid?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, druid

I want to write Spark batch results data to the Apache Druid. I know Druid has ***native batch ingestions*** such as `index_parallel`. Druid runs Map-Reduce jobs in the same cluster. But I only want to use Druid as a data storage. I want to aggregate data external Spark cluster, then send it to the Druid cluster.

Druid has `Tranquility` for real-time ingestion. I can send batch data using Tranquility, but this is not efficient. How can I send batch results to the Druid efficiently?

Comment: u can configure druid to listen on kafka topic. Spark gives u a connector to write to kafka. Another way .. you can write the output of ur spark job into parquet or json files. Druid can do local ingestion (u need to copy the files to one of the druid nodes) or you can do batch ingestion using HDFS

Comment: Kafka options is not good. Because, event times generally older than windowPartition. Another options seems good. I can write results as parquet format to the Druid's HDFS, then create a hdfs index to convert parquet to segments. This seems a good results, because data already aggregated, and just convert it to the segments. This seems it'll consumes lower resources than other options. Right?

Comment: HDFS way is the fastest and the most efficient way. u just have to put parquet into hdfs and give the location to druid. Btw, this way of ingestion replaces the existing segments in druid so make sure that u ingest the full data, not just the delta rows. Kafka on the other hand --works good to ingest just the delta rows; btw didnt understand `window partition` from ur reply --elaborate it.

Comment: ohh sorry. I tried to say `window period`. In real time ingestion, druid expects a window period. If any time of the received events is out of the specified window, this event ignored. As a results, results of batch analysis's times is always out of the window period(I assume window period is 10 minutes, and it can not be too large. This could be sufficient).

Answer (score 0):

You can write to Kafka topic and run Kafka Indexing Job to indexing it.

We have been using this mechanism for indexing data but there is no such restriction of windowPeriod in that. It takes even older timestamp. But if a shard is already finalized, this ends up creating new shards in same segment.

e.g. if I am using day size segment and I will get to shards in that segment
segment-11-11-2019-1 100MB
segment-11-11-2019-2 10MB ( for data received on 12th Nov with event time for 11th Nov ).

With compaction, these two shards will be merged with auto compaction turned on.

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-compaction.html

Or simply you can accumulate results in HDFS and then use Hadoop Batch ingestion using cron jobs. Auto compaction works well for this option too.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I am a contributor for rovio-ingest)

The [rovio-ingest](https://github.com/rovio/rovio-ingest) library allows ingesting any Spark dataset to Druid. The processing happens on a Spark cluster (that can be separate from the Druid server, as you required). Druid will discover the new/updated segments in the metadata storage. Writing big batches with this library is efficient, because the data is partitioned so that segment writing can be parallelized by Spark.